# What's the origin of the name of the "Chinese Cookie" found in Jewish deli's in the US?

Tags: cookies, history

At a classic Los Angeles Deli for lunch yesterday, I snagged my usual take-out guilty pleasure for later: a fresh-baked Chinese Cookie. This is a four or five inch diameter short-bread cookie with a dollop of chocolate frosting in the center. They appear to be a standard fare at every Deli I've visited.

The thing is, although it is unquestionably a cookie, there isn't anything obviously Chinese about it. So, why the name?

**Update:** [Here's a link](http://usa.kosher.com/store/kosher-bakery/zomicks-bakery-fresh-baked-goods/cookies-pastries-rugelach/228349-zomicks-kosher-large-chinese-cookies-package-of-2.html) to a kosher supplier's product page for their version of this cookie.

It is something I've only found in Jewish Deli's. Yesterday it was Langers across from MacArthur Park, but I've also had them from Cantor's on Fairfax, Brent's up in the Valley, and Billy's in Glendale.

The ingredients label on the wrapper of yesterday's says eggs, cake flour, sugar, shortening, baking powder, baking soda, chocolate.

Comment: I've actually never heard of these. Can you link to to a picture or something? A search for "chinese cookie" on Google just brings up fortune cookies.

Comment: For the same reason we have Dutch ovens, French fries, and creme Anglaise, I would imagine; either due to origin (unlikely I'm guessing), or using another nationality to indicate something is 'different'

Comment: I grew up in the L.A. area and I've never heard of anything like this. The only cookies I associate with the adjective "Chinese" are fortune cookies and almond cookies.

Comment: @Brendan, google is almost useless for things like this. In Google Image Search, fortune cookies dominate the results. If you add `-fortune` to the search, then you get almond cookies and several I don't know the names of. Cancel those terms, and you start getting pictures of cute Chinese girls in the mix. I stopped there.

Comment: @Marti, I think this is strictly a Jewish Deli thing, and not at all an LA-specific thing. I'm guessing they are found in New York Delis too....

Comment: @daniel, that is probably the true underlying reason, of course. I was just hoping there was a story behind the name that would help it make sense. :-)

Comment: I've eaten many kosher cookies of that type in New York and have never heard them called "Chinese" AFAIR. I think it must be a regional term. Maybe move the question to English.SE? Some of the etymology people may be able to help.

Answer (score 13):

The [recipe for Jewish Deli "Chinese Cookies"](http://thecowlesreport.com/fastestchef-035a.html) seems awfully similar to the [recipe](http://allrecipes.com//Recipe/chinese-restaurant-almond-cookies/Detail.aspx) for [Chinese almond biscuits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almond_Biscuit), except that the lard is replaced with shortening (to keep it Kosher) and chocolate is added.  A recipe for Chinese almond biscuits was printed as a "standard Chinese cookie" in [*The Thousand Recipe Chinese Cookbook*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671509934) as early as 1984, and this exact same recipe was reprinted in [*From Lokshen to Lo Mein: The Jewish Love Affair with Chinese Food*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9652293571).  Given that love affair with Chinese food, I am guessing that at some point in time a cook at a deli decided to recreate the beloved Chinese recipe, either due to his or her own love of the baked good or by request.

I know a Jewish guy who owned and operated a Chinese restaurant in the 1970s (staffed with Cantonese cooks), so the intercultural culinary collaboration is a definite possibility.  (Almond biscuits are very popular in Hong Kong, which is the epicenter of Cantonese cuisine.)  A [Glatt Kosher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shechita#Glatt) Israeli-style restaurant close to where I used to work recently converted to a Glatt Kosher Chinese-style restaurant (under the same management, and likely with the same cooks)!

**Edit (more speculation):** If the "Chinese cookie" is in fact a descendant of the almond biscuit, it may have been originally motivated by its almond content: It wouldn't be hard to replace the small amount of wheat flour in the recipe with something like almond flour, thus making the cookies Kosher for Passover.

**Edit (even more speculation):** [About 95% of the ethnic Chinese are lactose intolerant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lactose_intolerance#Lactose_intolerance_by_group).  Therefore, almost all Chinese confections are dairy-free.  If you think about it, there aren't many Western cookie recipes that don't call for some form of dairy.  The [laws of kashrut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kashrut) prohibit eating meat alongside dairy in a single meal.  In other words, if someone who keeps kosher were to eat a meal with meat, he or she would then have to follow it with a non-dairy desert.  Therefore, Jewish delis may have adapted a Chinese cookie recipe to provide non-dairy desert options for their kosher clientele.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't really answer your question; but I'm not sure you're going to get a better answer than "its origins are shrouded in historical mystery" as the following Jewish Life TV blog entry from 2009 asked a similar question but has, at least so far, not received any useful comments. It does suggest there's a link with the almond cookies found in Chinese bakeries, hence perhaps the name:

> The history of the Chinese Drop cookie is not well documented. If I were to write its history, I would fancy it would involve a Chinese baker, a Chinese Almond cookie, a Jewish Baker, and a dollop of chocolate and of course ground walnuts. From the blending of cultures, the Chinese Drop Cookie is born as a somewhat crumbly and crispy treat. Unlike its cousin, the Chinese Drop Cookie features the chocolate dollop and ground walnuts instead of the almonds.
>
> *Post a Comment: Have a good Chinese Drop Cookie recipe? Know the history of the Chinese Drop Cookie? Tell us about your favorite bakery.*
>
> **Source:** http://www.jltv.tv/blog.php?user=dumpling&blogentry_id=729